# Add number of months to each row in a series

Tags: python, pandas

I have a pandas dataframe (fb) with the date column orig_date. I want to add the number of months in the count_to_add column to the orig_date column, but the MonthEnd function isn't vectorized.

Here's what I tried:

```
fb["orig_date"] = fb["orig_date"] + 
                  pd.tseries.offsets.MonthEnd(fb["count_to_add"])
```

Since the series count_to_add isn't an integer, the MonthEnd function errors out.

Comment: See a relevant question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44003107/pandas-vectorized-date-offset-operations-with-vector-of-differing-offsets).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to add "number of months" only, use DateOffset instead.

```
fb['orig_date'] = fb.apply(lambda x: x['orig_date'] + pd.tseries.offsets.DateOffset(months=int(x['count_to_add'])), axis=1)
```