# Python Pandas - Translate date to fiscal year that follow 4-4-5 calendar

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm using Python Pandas to prep my data into series as inputs for timeseries modeling.

I have a dataframe with dates called DATE.  I tell Pandas its format (see below).  Since we use fiscal calendar, with end of the fiscal year being March, I use to_period("Q-MAR").  However, I also need to specify that we use 445 calendar.  For example, 12/30/2012 is supposed to be FY2013 Q4, and 3/29/2015 is FY2016 Q1.

The below, will translate 12/30/2012 to 2013Q3, and 3/29/2015 to 2015Q4:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DATE'], format="%m/%d/%Y")
df['fiscalyr'] = df['date'].dt.to_period("Q-MAR")
```

I've been messing around with QuarterFY5253 offset object in Pandas.  But I'm still lost.

I hope someone has encountered similar problem and can guide me!  Thank you.

Comment: How many records are there in the DataFrame?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44003107/pandas-vectorized-date-offset-operations-with-vector-of-differing-offsets

Comment: about 800,000 records

Comment: Were you able to find a solution to your problem? If so, could you please answer your question, thanks!