# Adding dates by months of integer type with NumPy

Tags: python, numpy, date

```
date = np.array(['2023-01-01', '2023-02-02', '2023-03-03'])
months = np.array([3, 2, 1])
months = np.array([np.timedelta64(month, 'M') for month in months])

expectation = date + months  ?????

# the array I want to get
# expectation -> np.array(['2023-04-01', '2023-04-02', '2023-04-03'])
```

I want to add the two variables "date", and "months". The `expectation` variable is what I want to get.

How to do it?

Comment: There is no real vectorized method for that, [see with pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44003107/pandas-vectorized-date-offset-operations-with-vector-of-differing-offsets)

Comment: But, the pandas method(dateOffset, and apply) is very slow in a big size data. It takes much of time. So, I'm looking for a vertorized way...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note: Part 1 of this answer assumes that the array has a `dtype='datetime64[D]'`, The difference from [RJ's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77306778/843953) is that I show a vectorized way to build your final result, since their answer has a sneaky loop in the form of a list comprehension in the last step, where they build `expectation`.

If the input array has a `dtype='U10'`, as would be the case if you ran the statement `date = np.array(['2023-01-01', '2023-02-02', '2023-03-03'])`, skip to part 2.

##### Part 1: If `date.dtype == 'datetime64[D]'`

Calculate `new_years` and `new_months` exactly like RJ shows in their answer:

```
# Given date and months arrays
date = np.array(['2023-01-01', '2023-02-02', '2023-03-03'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
months = np.array([3, 2, 1])

# Extracting year, month, and day components
years = date.astype('datetime64[Y]').astype(int) + 1970
months_from_date = date.astype('datetime64[M]').astype(int) % 12 + 1
days = date.astype('datetime64[D]') - date.astype('datetime64[M]')

# Adding the respective month values and handling overflow
new_months = months_from_date + months
new_years = years + (new_months - 1) // 12
new_months = (new_months - 1) % 12 + 1
```

Then, construct your result by reversing the steps you used to deconstruct the dates into year, month and day:

```
expectation = (new_years - 1970).astype('datetime64[Y]') + \
              new_months.astype('timedelta64[M]') + \
              days
```

This gives you the required array

```
array(['2023-05-01', '2023-05-02', '2023-05-03'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

##### Part 2: If `date.dtype == '<U10'`

For an alternative to RJ's approach to split the input string array into date, month, and years: you can get these directly from the characters of your string array instead of converting to a datetime array:

First, convert to a `(N, 10)` array of characters:

```
>>> date_chars = date.view('U1').reshape((-1, 10))

array([['2', '0', '2', '3', '-', '0', '1', '-', '0', '1'],
       ['2', '0', '2', '3', '-', '0', '2', '-', '0', '2'],
       ['2', '0', '2', '3', '-', '0', '3', '-', '0', '3']], dtype='<U1')
```

Next, get the years, months, and days by slicing this array:

```
>>> years = date_chars[:, :4].view('U4').astype(int)

array([[2023],
       [2023],
       [2023]])

>>> months_from_date = date_chars[:, 5:7].view('U2').astype(int)

array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])

>>> days = date_chars[:, 8:10].view('U2').astype(int)

array([[1],
       [2],
       [3]])
```

Since all these arrays are column vectors, let's convert `months` to a column vector so that the numpy doesn't broadcast the results into square matrices:

```
>>> months = np.array([3, 2, 1])
... months = months[:, None]

array([[3],
       [2],
       [1]])
```

Then, create `new_months` and `new_years` as they showed:

```
>>> new_months = months_from_date + months
... new_years = years + (new_months - 1) // 12
... new_months = (new_months - 1) % 12 + 1
```

Finally, build your new dates:

Create a character array of the same size as `date_chars`, but full of the character `'0'`. Insert hyphens into the correct locations:

```
>>> new_date_chars = np.full_like(date_chars, '0', dtype='U1')
... new_date_chars[:, 4] = '-'
... new_date_chars[:, 7] = '-'

array([['0', '0', '0', '0', '-', '0', '0', '-', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '-', '0', '0', '-', '0', '0'],
       ['0', '0', '0', '0', '-', '0', '0', '-', '0', '0']], dtype='<U1')
```

Before the next step, let's define a helper function that will take in a numeric array (of days or months), and return an array of characters with zeros padded:

```
def to_chars_pad_zero(arr):
    char_arr = arr.astype('U2').view('U1')
    one_digit_nums = (arr < 10).squeeze()
    char_arr[one_digit_nums, 1] = char_arr[one_digit_nums, 0]
    char_arr[one_digit_nums, 0] = '0'
    return char_arr
```

Then, insert the year, month, and dates:

```
>>> new_date_chars[:, :4] = new_years.astype('U4').view('U1')

array([['2', '0', '2', '3', '-', '0', '0', '-', '0', '0'],
       ['2', '0', '2', '3', '-', '0', '0', '-', '0', '0'],
       ['2', '0', '2', '3', '-', '0', '0', '-', '0', '0']], dtype='<U1')

>>> new_date_chars[:, 5:7] = to_chars_pad_zero(new_months)

array([['2', '0', '2', '3', '-', '0', '4', '-', '0', '0'],
       ['2', '0', '2', '3', '-', '0', '4', '-', '0', '0'],
       ['2', '0', '2', '3', '-', '0', '4', '-', '0', '0']], dtype='<U1')

>>> new_date_chars[:, 8:] = to_chars_pad_zero(days)

array([['2', '0', '2', '3', '-', '0', '4', '-', '0', '1'],
       ['2', '0', '2', '3', '-', '0', '4', '-', '0', '2'],
       ['2', '0', '2', '3', '-', '0', '4', '-', '0', '3']], dtype='<U1')
```

Finally, join these into a string:

```
>>> new_dates = new_date_chars.view('U10').squeeze()

array(['2023-04-01', '2023-04-02', '2023-04-03'], dtype='<U10')
```

Answer (score 1):

Because the lengths of months varies offsetting dates can be tricky using numpy. However, you can achieve this by extracting the year, month, and day components, performing the addition, and then reassembling the date.

Here's one approach:

```
import numpy as np

# Given date and months arrays
date = np.array(['2023-01-01', '2023-02-02', '2023-03-03'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
months = np.array([3, 2, 1])

# Extracting year, month, and day components
years = date.astype('datetime64[Y]').astype(int) + 1970
months_from_date = date.astype('datetime64[M]').astype(int) % 12 + 1
days = date.astype('datetime64[D]') - date.astype('datetime64[M]')

# Adding the respective month values and handling overflow
new_months = months_from_date + months
new_years = years + (new_months - 1) // 12
new_months = (new_months - 1) % 12 + 1

# Constructing the new datetime64[D] array and adding back the day component
expectation = np.array(["{}-{:02}-01".format(y, m) for y, m in zip(new_years, new_months)], dtype='datetime64[D]')
expectation_with_days = expectation + days
```

Output:

```
array(['2023-04-01', '2023-04-02', '2023-04-03'], dtype='datetime64[D]')
```

Comment: There is a sneaky loop in the form of a list comprehension in the "constructing the new array" step

Comment: @pho yes, good catch!